# Official Youtube - client side error (400) malformed or illegal request

Tags: security, browser, youtube, heap-memory

Very frequently official YouTube website errors out. It works in incognito mode if I try. Which tells me the issue is due to one of cookies / cache / localstorage / application-data on the browser.

If I delete the data, it will start working again, but, I will need to sign-in again in all the gmail-accounts that I use.

I've asked Google (in feedback and over twitter) to look into this but they can't help it.

So, questions:

- If anyone has faced this issue, have you figured out why and how to fix it without signing out from accounts?
- How do I go about debugging this?
- I've taken a memory heap snapshot on chrome but have no idea how to analyze it.
- Is sending a memory heap snapshot as part of feedback or to anyone else secure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out the solution. Tried looking at patterns in general in the memory of the browser (localstorage, etc) and found the following in **cookies** and here's what fixed it (without signing me out of my accounts).

In the image below - there are lines which have `gsScrollPos-xyz` with a past expiry date. I deleted all of those. I understand that only Google will be able to figure out why that caused the issue and I will send them the feedback.

[image]